# Where is the WiFi antenna located?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, hardware, streetpass

Where in the body of the Nintendo 3DS is the WiFi antenna located?

To try to get more StreetPasses, I place the 3DS in an indent on my car's dashboard when I'm driving.  Which part of the 3DS do I have to ensure is above the metal cage of car for the best chance of success?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've gotten streetpasses with my 3DS in my pocket while driving, and also with it in my work bag in the passenger seat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for part one of your question, the wifi antenna is wrapped around the touch screen as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Great answer.  Why write when when you can just show a picture. ;)

Comment: When assembled, is it wrapped around all 4 sides of the screen?  Is it the same strength on all 4 sides?

Comment: The majority of the antenna is lined up passing through the top and right side of the screen.  I wish I could provide you with more information on maximizing the signal strength based on it's orientation, but I can say that in general StreetPass can reach approximately 30 meters.